# Flutter screen came Below the Native Android Module Page

Tags: android, flutter, module, flutter-dependencies

I have One Flutter Page in the Flutter Plugin and inside that there is a button, Now, On press of that button, I am opening a Android Native Module Activity. That Module Activity Has a Button, On tap of that Button I Am sending notification using EventBus and get that response in the Android code in the plugin. Then the control also I can send in the flutter code. Now I want to open a Overlay or any transparent page on top of the Native Library activity, I can open the Flutter page or overlay but it came below of that activity. Is there any way to make Flutter screen On top of the Native Library code? There should not be any circular dependency is another requirement.

I have tried to open a Flutter Activity also from the android code of the plugin, instead of calling the native library, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> PHIND V7 MODEL

To display a Flutter overlay on top of a native Android activity, you can use the flutter_overlay_window package pub.dev. This package allows you to display your Flutter app over other apps on the screen. However, it's important to note that this package only works on Android.

1. First, add the flutter_overlay_window package to your pubspec.yaml file:

> ```
> dependencies:
>  flutter_overlay_window: ^0.4.3
> ```

2. Then, import the package in your Dart file:

> import 'package:flutter_overlay_window/flutter_overlay_window.dart';
> 3. Create a method to show the overlay window. This method will create a new Flutter view, add it to the window manager, and show the overlay:
>
> ```
> void showOverlayWindow() async {
>  // Create a new Flutter view
>  await FlutterOverlayWindow.create(
>    context: context,
>    x: 100,
>    y: 100,
>    width: 300,
>    height: 300,
>    isFocusable: true,
>    isFloating: true,
>    isDraggable: true,
>    isResizable: true,
>    isTranslucent: true,
>    isVisible: true,
>    isOnTop: true,
>  );
>
>  // Add the Flutter view to the window manager
>  await FlutterOverlayWindow.addToWindowManager(
>    x: 100,
>    y: 100,
>    width: 300,
>    height: 300,
>  );
>
>  // Show the overlay
>  await FlutterOverlayWindow.show();
> }
> ```

4. Finally, call the showOverlayWindow method when the button in your native Android activity is tapped:

> ```
> onPressed: () {
>  showOverlayWindow();
> }
> ```

This will create an overlay window with your Flutter app on top of the native Android activity.

However, if you want to display a Flutter page or overlay on top of a native Android activity without using a package, you can use the Stack widget in Flutter stackoverflow.com. This widget allows you to overlay several children in a simple way.

Here is an example of how to use the Stack widget to overlay a Flutter page on top of a native Android activity:

> ```
> Stack(
>  children: [
>    // Your native Android activity
>    AndroidView(
>      viewType: 'your_native_android_activity',
>    ),
>    // Your Flutter overlay
>    Positioned(
>      top: 0,
>      left: 0,
>      child: FlutterOverlay(),
>    ),
>  ],
> )
> ```

In this example, the AndroidView widget is used to display the native Android activity, and the Positioned widget is used to position the Flutter overlay on top of the native Android activity.